# React passing parameters with URL

Tags: reactjs

Im developing a React application. When the user clicks on the view-button on a list view, I want that to be redirected to the view page with the item_id. I tried to use the hyperlink (< a> tag) tag to do this but it doesnt navigate with item_id of the clicked row. I want to know how to pass parameters with URL in react.

This is the code I tried.

```
 <a className="btn btn-info btn-xs" href={'/#/fld-view/:id'} title="View"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

Comment: you should look into react-router

Comment: You'll need to use react router for this: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

refer tutorial here:https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons

Answer (score 1):

Component `Link` from `react-router` would be the solution. Also, to add the props (in your case the id) to a string, you should go this way :

```
href={`/#/fld-view/${id}`} //ES6 or ES7 if I remember
```

if you aren't using it :

```
href={'/#/fld-view/' + id}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Alexander.

Comment: if you haven't declared you props in the render function (like this: const { id} = this.props; ) you would have to put in the url this.props.id instead of only id. If it works, make sure to set my answer as the good answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use the `<a>` tag use the `<Link></Link>` tags from react-router

```
<Link to={
      {
        pathname: match.url + '/view',
        search:'? itemview1=' + id_1  
       }
  }>GO TO A VIEW</Link>
```